# How to define a custom object as a role in QAbstractListModel?

Tags: qml, qt5, qabstractlistmodel

My question is, that how can I specify a custom object as a role in a model derived from `QAbstractListModel` so when visualizing it within a `ListView` I can access its member variables. To have an example here is some simple code example:

This is my class representing my custom object:

```
class MyCustomObject {
  public:
    MyCustomObject(Qstring name, Qstring type);
    QString getName();
    QString getType();

  private:
    QString name;
    QString type;
};
```

This is how the overridden `data()` function looks like now (but it is not working) of my `MyModel` derived from `QAbsractListModel`:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() > m_atoms.count()) {
    //if (!index.isValid()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    const MyData &data = m_data[index.row()];
    if(role == SomeRole) {
        return data.someString()
    }
    else if (role == MyCustomRole) {
        return data.myCustomObject; // How can I do this?
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

Here I specify the role names in `MyModel`:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> AtomModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[SomeRole] = "someRole";
    roles[MyCustomRole] = "myCustomRole";

    return roles;
}
```

and this is how my `ListView` looks like in QML code with an example how I would like to access `MyCustomObject` member variables in the delegate:

```
ListView {
        width: 400
        height: 400

        model: myModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: "Type: " + myCustomRole.getType() + ", Name: " + myCustomRole.getName() + ", some string: " someRole

        }
    }
```

---

EDIT1: => fix needed copy constructor

When I am adding Q_DECLARE_METATYPE under my `MyCustomObject` I receive the following error:

```
call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of `MyCustomObject`
in instantiation of member function 'QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<MyCustomObject, true>::Construct' requested here
in instantiation of function template specialization 'qRegisterNormalizedMetaType<MyCustomObject>' requested here QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<T>::Construct,
    return qRegisterNormalizedMetaType<T>(normalizedTypeName, dummy, defined);
in instantiation of function template specialization 'qRegisterMetaType<MyCustomObject>' requested here
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyCustomObject)
expanded from macro 'Q_DECLARE_METATYPE'
#define Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE) Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_IMPL(TYPE)
expanded from macro 'Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_IMPL' 
      const int newId = qRegisterMetaType< TYPE >(#TYPE,
copy constructor of 'MyCustomObject' is implicitly deleted because base class 'QObject' has a deleted copy constructor
class MyCustomObject : public QObject
'QObject' has been explicitly marked deleted here Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
expanded from macro 'Q_DISABLE_COPY'
       Class(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;\
```

---

EDIT2:

So I have added all the necessary functions what @Evgeny has suggested. My code now compiles without errors, but I get a qml error on run time saying:
`TypeError: Property 'getType' of object QVariant(MyCustomObject) is not a function`

I have added `Q_INVOKABLE` in front of the `getType()` method and I also deriving `MyCustomObject` class from `public QObject`. I have added `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` at the bottom of my `MyCustomObject` header file. In the constructor of `MyCustomObject` I call `qRegisterMetaType<MyCustomObject>("MyCustomObject")` and in my `main` I register the class also like this `qmlRegisterType<MyCustomObject>("com.test.mycustomobject", 1, 0, "MyCustomObject")`

This is how `MyCustomObject` class looks like now:

```
class MyCustomObject : public QObject {
  public:
    MyCustomObject();
    MyCustomObject(Qstring name, Qstring type);
    MyCustomObject(const MyCustomObject& obj);
    ~MyCustomObject();
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getName();
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getType();

  private:
    QString name;
    QString type;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyCustomObject)
```

This is how the overridden `data()` function looks like now of my `MyModel` derived from `QAbsractListModel`:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() > m_atoms.count()) {
        //if (!index.isValid()) {
            return QVariant();
        }

        const MyData &data = m_data[index.row()];
        if(role == SomeRole) {
            return data.someString()
        }
        else if (role == MyCustomRole) {
            QVariant var; // this is the part, which has changed
            var.setValue(data.myCustomObject);
            return var;
        }

        return QVariant();
    }
```

All other functions which I have posted originally are the same.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to declare your custom object for Qt metatype system. You should use [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) macro for this. Also you may need to use [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) function. Then you should register your object to use it with QML. You should use [`qmlRegisterType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) function for that.

Also make sure you use [`Q_INVOKABLE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) for your objects methods.

Comment: I am going to try it, will get back with the results!

Comment: Unfortunately as soon as I put `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` under my `MyCustomObject` I get error saying: calling to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of `MyCustomObject`. (For more detailed error message see my EDIT1)

Comment: Maybe you should read documentation first?

>Any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor can be registered.

Comment: True, my mistake...I actually read the docs, but I thought I have a copy constructor since I usually follow rule of three, but I forgot to make one for this "dummy" example. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Now the code builds but I get an error from qml on console. I have added the details under EDIT2.

Comment: Try to use `Q_PROPERTY` for accessing `myCustomObject` methods.

Comment: It works now, thanks for the guiding me! Will post the code when I will have some more time.